# Does "will" and other auxiliary verbs spread on all the sentence?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

Consider the following example — I want to write down several sequential actions in future. Should I write:

> I will go home, will have dinner, will play tennis, etc.

or:

> I will go home, have dinner, play tennis, etc.

And the same for *would*, *have*, and other auxiliaries. Is there a common rule?

P.S.: There is [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28454/do-i-have-to-use-the-auxiliary-before-all-the-verbs) on a similar topic, but I don't know if separating verbs by comma and by *and* is equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example sentence treats the three activities as a sequential list, so the timing of them is given by the order they happen in.

The introductory phrase for the list is "I will", so that is applied to all items in the list -- and that also goes for lists introduced with modal auxiliaries:

"If I had the money, I would a, b, and c" means "~~ I would a, I would b, and I would c".

You can, of course, repeat the subject + modal for emphasis (particularly with "will", which is used for making promises):

"I *will* do a, I *will* do b, and I *will* do c, even if it kills... er... someone!"

But, given that you clearly state that the actions are a sequence, it is plain that all of the actions will occur in the future, because the first action has the "will", and the other actions follow it in sequence.